# How to set an open excel file as a Workbook object in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I need to set an excel file that is already open on the computer as the workbook object.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set wb = *the open excel file*
Set sh = wb.Worksheets("FlatFile-FichierPlat")
```

Comment: And how do you guarantee that the current open excel file is the one you expect? Users do crazy things like opening multiple files or Excel instances.

Answer (score 3):

```
Set wb = Workbooks("yourWorkbookName")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the workbook name will not always the same.

Comment: but you should know which workbook you want to work with

Answer (score 3):

If your code is opening the file, then you already have the object reference:

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Application.Workbooks.Open(path) 'reference is returned by the Open function
```

If the user can open the file at any arbitrary point in time, then you need to handle the `Application.WorkbookOpen` event - you can do that by declaring a `Private WithEvents {name} As Excel.Application` object variable at module scope in `ThisWorkbook`, and setting its reference to `Application` when `ThisWorkbook` opens, i.e. in the `Workbook_Open` handler:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set app = Application
End Sub

Private Sub app_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    'Wb holds the object reference for the new workbook that was created
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    'Wb holds the object reference for the workbook that was opened
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `GetObject` to get a reference to the Excel application running it, and then iterate the workbook collection:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set wb = GetObject( ,"Excel.Application").ActiveWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Worksheets("FlatFile-FichierPlat")
```

For more information, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getobject-function).